# Why Intel i5-8350u is faster than AMD Ryzen 2700x in Python script in single core?

Tags: cpu, performance, python, intel-core-i5, amd-ryzen

I have strange situation.
Long story short, laptop with Intel i5-8350u runs Python script twice faster in single core than AMD Ryzen 2700x.

**Now a bit more details.**
Firstly, specs of the machines.
AMD
Ryzen 2700x(stock)
16 GB of DDR4@2133(Dual channel)
Data on SATA HDD

INTEL
i5-8350u
16 GB of DDR4@2400(Dual channel)
Data on UBS3 HDD

Laptop runs Mac OS X Catalina 10.15.2 with latest Anaconda and Python 3.8.1.
Desktop runs Ubuntu 18.04.3 with latest Anaconda and Python 3.8.1 as well. The sole detail that I have built numpy with openblas.

The script is generation of [CornerPlot](https://corner.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) from a posterior files. There are 300 objects in total. I have serial and parallel versions of this code and the result are following :

**Results**

```
i5 - 21m22s in single and 6m25s in parallel  
ryzen - 40m44s in single and 3m34s in parallel
```

Is that normal? Anything I can do to improve Ryzen performance?

OBS: I'm aware of dependency of Ryzen on memory, probably I will try to overclock and retest.

OBS2: I'm implying something similar. So there is maybe some software fix. - > [AMD-Ryzen-3900X-vs-Intel-Xeon-2175W](https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/hpc/AMD-Ryzen-3900X-vs-Intel-Xeon-2175W-Python-numpy---MKL-vs-OpenBLAS-1560/)

Comment: Intel CPU's always had better single-core performance than AMD and AMD has a slight advantage on the multi-core performance. It's always been like this (there is a technical explanation but I'm not very aware of it). If you want to improve Ryzen's performance you either run the script on more cores/overclock it for a slight difference.

Comment: I suggest you try a benchmark program on both to verify actual memory and cpu speed. As well as HDD benchmarks. RAM is probably the issue though, as well as possible optimization.

Comment: @CaldeiraG Sure, Im aware of Intel edge in single core performance. But the case here is that Im comparing Desktop vs. Laptop CPUs and receiving huge difference...

Comment: Single core performance should be vaguely comparable: https://www.cpubenchmark.net/compare/Intel-i5-8350U-vs-AMD-Ryzen-7-PRO-2700X/3150vs3292 so I'm surprised at such a big difference. How large in GB is the set of files? What actually is the "USB3 HDD", is it an SSD? Could it be disk access times being slow?

Comment: @Mokubai Total size of input data is about 17GB. Each object is between 50 and 100 MB. USB3 HDD is HardDisk connected via USB3 external port.

Comment: It is still possible that the USB 3 disk is faster it might be a that the desktop has a "Red" or RAID type disk that runs at 5400RPM while the one in the external enclosure is at 7200RPM. I've got two disks in my machine, a 4TB Red which manages maybe 100MB/s, but the 3TB normal drive manages 160-170MB/s. Over 17GB that would be a significant difference in time and disk latency plays a factor too. Try using [Crystaldiskmark](https://crystalmark.info/en/software/crystaldiskmark/) to benchmark the two disks.

Answer (score 1):

Anaconda uses Intel MKL as default BLAS library, which runs slow on AMD processors (see [Ryzen and Intel's Anti-competitive MKL](https://www.reddit.com/r/Amd/comments/du3rhq/ryzen_and_intels_anticompetitive_mkl/)).

You have a couple of choices. I'd really appreciate if you could try both them and report here the results (as a comment).

1. just set the environment variable `MKL_DEBUG_CPU_TYPE=5`; see [here](https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/hpc/How-To-Use-MKL-with-AMD-Ryzen-and-Threadripper-CPU-s-Effectively-for-Python-Numpy-And-Other-Applications-1637/#UsingMKL_DEBUG_CPU_TYPE=5withAMDCPU%5C's) for more information; this will "fool MKL into using an AVX2 optimization level on AMD CPU's";
2. install the conda package `nomkl` to opt out of MKL and use OpenBLAS instead; see "Uninstalling MKL" on [this page](https://docs.anaconda.com/mkl-optimizations/).

You should see a huge improvement with both solutions. Nonetheless, note that AMD CPUs before those with Zen2 architecture (3rd gen) are slower than Intel CPUs on executing AVX2 instructions for architectural reasons.

**EDIT:** sorry, I misread the command I had pasted in solution 2 (`conda install -c anaconda nomkl`). It doesn't create a new environment, as I wrote, it just installs nomkl. I removed the command add a link that explain everything you need to do to remove MKL in detail.